# iPhone:How to merge the characters at the index of array into the text:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have an array of characters like

```
shuffleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"H",@"E",@"L",@"L",@"O", nil];
```

and I want to generate the string of these characters like "HELLO".

then How can I do this?

any help will be appreciable.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *word = [shuffleArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Should do it…